# Using containsObject with object arrays from different files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, comparison, nsmutablearray

So I have a class called ArtPiece that defines several attributes of public artpieces such as title, description, etc.  I store ArtPiece objects in an array called mapAnnotations in the appDelegate so they will be global, and they will be put on a map as annotations. When the map region changes I make a URL call to get the information of artpieces that entered the region, make artPiece objects from the parsed info, then add them to an array called items in a class called "ArtsXMLParser". I want mapAnnotations to hold all the artpieces that are on the map, but when the region changes I want to add only the artpieces from "items" that are not already in mapAnnotations, so as to not put duplicate annotations on the map. Here is a method in a third class that manages the annotations. Everything seems to work, but the if statement with containsObject: gets called everytime, so apparently the artpieces are never matching although when they are logged they have the same info. Is there a better way to see if two arrays have an object with the exact same attributes in common?

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    //NSLog(@"requestFinished:");

    //NSLog(@"%@", [request responseString]);
    mainDelegate = (PublicArtAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];      
    ArtsXMLParser *parser = [[ArtsXMLParser alloc] init];
    [parser parseXMLWithData:[request responseData] parseError:nil];
    newAnnots = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int xy = 0; xy<[parser items].count; xy++) 
    {
        if (![mainDelegate.mapAnnotations containsObject:[[parser items]objectAtIndex:xy]])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", [[parser items]objectAtIndex:xy]);
            [self.newAnnots addObject:[[parser items]objectAtIndex:xy]];            
            NSLog(@"%@", [newAnnots objectAtIndex:xy]);
            [mainDelegate.mapAnnotations addObject:[[parser items]objectAtIndex:xy]];
            NSLog(@"%@", [mainDelegate.mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:xy]);
        }
    }
    //mainDelegate.mapAnnotations = [parser items];
    [parser release];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.newAnnots];
    [newAnnots removeAllObjects];
    //[mainDelegate.mapAnnotations addObject:newAnnots];
    [newAnnots release];
    if (mainDelegate.mapAnnotations==0) {
        UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"No art work match your search term" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert2 show];
        [alert2 release];
    }
}
```

I'll be happy to clarify anything that wasn't explained well. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ArtPiece` object you need to subclass the `isEqual:` method so that it returns YES when two artPieces are equal. The default implementation of this method just compares pointer values for individual objects, which, in your case, is not what you want.

See Apple's documentation on the [`isEqual:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a) method for some details that you need to be aware of when subclassing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! So in the isEqual method is the "receiver" the object before the containsObject:, and "other" is the one after? And how do I refer to the receiver in the method?

Comment: Inside the `isEqual:` method, `self` refers to the receiver.